# Pandas df.corr - one variable across multiple cols

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I'd like to create a correlation with one variable as the independent, and multiple additional variables as the dependent, and then turn it into a heat map.

I'm following these [directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896455/how-to-do-pearson-correlation-of-selected-columns-of-a-pandas-data-frame).

My code:

```
df_corr_interest = df[df.columns[0:11]].corr()['impact_action_yn'][:-1]
#set fig size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15))
#plot matrix
sns.heatmap(df_corr_interest, square=True,annot=True, annot_kws={'size':12},cmap="GnBu")
plt.show();
```

I'm getting the following error: `KeyError: 'impact_action_yn'`

Dataframe:

```
ExternalReference   interest_el interest_pl interest_ad interest_ol commitment_elected  commitment_policy   commitment_advocacy commitment_organizing   timeline_elected    ... Policy  Organizing  Engagement  Parent  Veteran first_gen_american  first_gen_college   ri_region   LGBTQ   Gender
0   0034000001RHCU0AAP  1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   Woman
1   00340000015yDbOAAU  1   1   1   2   0   0   0   2   0   ... 0   1   2   0   0   0   0   1   0   Man
2   0034000000y3QjMAAU  1   2   2   2   0   2   3   4   0   ... 5   2   3   0   0   0   0   1   0   Man
3   0034000001qcNXRAA2  1   1   1   3   0   0   0   3   0   ... 0   1   6   0   0   0   0   1   0   Woman
4   0034000001DVPedAAH  1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   Woman
```

Thoughts?

Updated with full list of vars:

```
ExternalReference                   object
interest_el                          int64
interest_pl                          int64
interest_ad                          int64
interest_ol                          int64
commitment_elected                   int64
commitment_policy                    int64
commitment_advocacy                  int64
commitment_organizing                int64
timeline_elected                     int64
timeline_policy                      int64
timeline_advocacy                    int64
timeline_organizing                  int64
interest_appointed                 float64
interest_vol_organizing            float64
interest_school_organizing         float64
impact_action_yn                   float64
impact_action_public_action        float64
impact_action_testified            float64
impact_action_met_el               float64
impact_action_lobbied              float64
impact_action_bill                 float64
impact_action_other                float64
impact_action_other_text            object
impact_topic_charter_schools       float64
impact_topics_ece                  float64
impact_topics_postsecondary        float64
impact_topics_school_choice        float64
impact_topics_student_achv         float64
impact_topics_district_perf        float64
impact_topics_wraparound           float64
impact_topics_school_discipline    float64
impact_topics_special_pops         float64
impact_topics_teacher_tenure       float64
impact_topics_other                float64
impact_topics_other_text            object
impact_role                         object
impact_level                       float64
impact_level_text                   object
impact_success                     float64
impact_other_comments               object
Advocacy                             int64
Elected                              int64
Policy                               int64
Organizing                           int64
Engagement                           int64
Parent                               int64
Veteran                              int64
first_gen_american                   int64
first_gen_college                    int64
ri_region                            int64
LGBTQ                                int64
Gender                              object
dtype: object
```

Comment: In the example you've provided, there is no column called `'impact_action_yn'`. By using a column name that does exist, such as `'commitment_organizing'`, the first line runs fine for me.

Comment: Yes, it does run fine with that other var. impact_action_yn is a float64. I'm just realizing that the other float64 vars have the same issue. It seems as if I need to convert them to int? The float64 vars work fine in my big corr table (every var v. every var).

Comment: Works fine for me even with `float64` columns. By restricting yourself to `df[df.columns[0:11]]`, you are only using the first 11 columns; Could it be that `'impact_action_yn'` is simply among the first 11 columns? (Certainly, it's not among the first 10 that you show.)

Comment: It's 16. (Updated above w/ full list of vars).

Comment: That explains it then.

Comment: Oh... do I need to include it in ```[df.columns[0:11]]```? 
so it's [df.columns[0:16]]

Comment: Ok, now I"m getting: ```IndexError: Inconsistent shape between the condition and the input (got (15, 1) and (15,))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Needed df.to_frame()

Full code:

```
df_corr_impact_action_yn = df[df.columns[0:17]].corr()['impact_action_yn'][:-1]
#set fig size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,25))
#plot matrix
sns.heatmap(df_corr_impact_action_yn.to_frame(),annot=True, annot_kws={'size':12},cmap="GnBu")
plt.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

By running `df[df.columns[0:11]].corr()`, you are taking the pair-wise correlations between each of the first 11 columns, but `'impact_action_yn'` being the 15th column, none of its correlations enter the result. Instead, you could just do `df.corr()` and remove any unnecessary correlations afterwards.

After that, you'll run into the issue that `sns.reshape` expects a matrix; you can take care of that by replacing `['impact_action_yn']` with `[['impact_action_yn']]`.

Comment: True, but I wanted to then take those corr for a specific var and turn it into a heatmap.

Comment: `df.corr` calculates all possible correlations, so by doing that, and then restricting to `'impact_action_yn'`, you get the correlations of that variable with all others.

Comment: Solved it. Posted above.

Comment: Applying `to_frame` is exactly equivalent to just taking `[['impact_action_yn']]`.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that! Thanks